# Saving "skipped" nodes in xml into array

Tags: c#, xml, arrays

In my code, I am downloading an xml file, and because one of the nodes is variable (both name and count of them), I use code like this:

```
XmlNodeList arrivals = airplanes.SelectNodes("/myXml/flights/*/arrivals");
```

Now what I need to do, is saving names of the nodes skipped by "*" into an array, or arraylist, something like that. Later I will need to use some foreach to do something with each of the nodes, now saved as strings. I have tried

```
foreach(* in MyArrayList)
```

and that doesnt work, I get a number of errors there, assuming I cant use the " * " here.

Comment: Note: I have tried that foreach with different ArrayList just to check if its possible, I still dont know how to save the names of the nodes.

Comment: can you select to XmlNodeList all the nodes you skiped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `XmlNode` in the `XmlNodeList` has a `ParentNode` property, you should be able to use that to navigate back up from the `arrivals` node in the xml to the `*` node.

The following Linq query should get the names:

```
var names = arrivals.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(x => x.ParentNode.Name).ToList();
```

The `Cast<XmlNode>` is needed because XmlNodeList doesn't implement the generic `IEnumerable` interface.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response. I cant access my code right now, I will try this out tomorrow ;) Thank you.

Comment: @MarekBuchtela no problem, are you using .NET 3.5 or later?